# How can I create dictionary in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a array,

```
months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
```

and I want to make it as dictionary like

```
months = {1:'January', 2:'February',....}
```

I tried `enumerate()` but did not have any luck.
How can I assign sequence number to the list in order to make dictionary?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with enumerate you could do it like this:

```
months =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

d_months = {}

for i, month in enumerate(months):
    d_months[i+1] = month

print(d_months)
```

output:

```
{1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
```

Since enumerate starts at 0 you need to use `[i+1]`

Answer (score 4):

Since the `dict()` constructor builds a dictionary directly from key-value pairs, this also works:

```
dict(enumerate(months, 1))
```

Here are some tests, even though this isn't really important for your use-case:

```
timeit dict(enumerate(months, 1))
The slowest run took 10.34 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 µs per loop

timeit {i:m for i,m in enumerate(months,1)}
The slowest run took 7.77 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 µs per loop

timeit {i+1:months[i] for i in range(12)}
The slowest run took 5.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing comparison. Did you write that code?

Answer (score 2):

Try out this.

```
months=
['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

dict = {i+1:months[i] for i in range(12)}
```

As pointed out in the comments, use range(len(months)). Since the length of the list is known in this case, I've used 12.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev Yup. should have mentioned that. Since we know the length in advance in this case I didn't see the need. Will edit my answer :)

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal I used `range` too. Thank you!

Comment: You could also use `enumerate`, as in `{i+1:m for i,m in enumerate(months)}`, just in case they add some extra months someday ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `eumerate` like this to force it to start with 1.

```
months =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
months = {i:m for i,m in enumerate(months,1)}
print months
```

Will produce

```
{1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
{i:months[i] for i in range(len(months))}
```